MQTT brokerを自作したい
やりたいこと
MQTTプロトコルの勉強として、brokerを自作しようと考えています。
バージョンはMQTT v3.1で行いたいです。
やったこと
MQTTのパケット構造はドキュメントをきちんと読んだので理解はできています。
TCP接続された回線で、MQTTプロトコルは通信を行うとのことだったので、pythonでsocketを使ってsocket通信まで行うところまでできています。
躓いていること
MQTTプロトコルの構造をした、パケットを作成したいです。
ただ、どのようにパケットを作成すれないいのか、勉強不足で分からないです。
教えてほしいこと
キーワードでも構いません。　パケットを自分で作れるようになるために、参考にすべきコードや本、サイト様などがありましたら、教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

「MQTTプロトコルの構造をした、パケットを作成」に躓いている, というのが何を指してるのか分かりづらいです。バイナリデータの作り方の質問？
/ あと「socket通信まで」できているとのことですが, TCPは UDPのメッセージ指向(比較的単純) とは異なりストリーム指向なのでそこ注意したほうがよいかも

バイナリデータの作り方です。

TCPは UDPのメッセージ指向(比較的単純) とは異なりストリーム指向なのでそこ注意したほうがよいかも

分かりました。　ありがとうございます。


バイナリデータの作り方です

バイナリデータ扱うには以下のパッケージを利用するとよいかもです

struct --- バイト列をパックされたバイナリデータとして解釈する
必要であれば, enum --- 列挙型 なども

実際に, MQTT V3.1 Protocol Specification から "2. Message format" 内の "2.1. Fixed header" 部分を扱ってみます
(名称は適当)
import struct
from enum import Enum

class MessageType(Enum):
    Reserved    = 0 # Reserved
    CONNECT     = 1 # Client request to connect to Server
    CONNACK     = 2 # Connect Acknowledgment
    PUBLISH     = 3 # Publish message
    PUBACK      = 4 # Publish Acknowledgment
    PUBREC      = 5 # Publish Received (assured delivery part 1)
    PUBREL      = 6 # Publish Release (assured delivery part 2)
    PUBCOMP     = 7 # Publish Complete (assured delivery part 3)
    SUBSCRIBE   = 8 # Client Subscribe request
    SUBACK      = 9 # Subscribe Acknowledgment
    UNSUBSCRIBE = 10    # Client Unsubscribe request
    UNSUBACK    = 11    # Unsubscribe Acknowledgment
    PINGREQ     = 12    # PING Request
    PINGRESP    = 13    # PING Response
    DISCONNECT  = 14    # Client is Disconnecting
    # Reserved  = 15    # Reserved

flagsDUP = 0b1000
flagsQoS1 = 1 <<1
flagsQoS2 = 2 <<1
flagsQoS3 = 3 <<1
flagsRETAIN = 1

structでネットワーク・バイトオーダーを(複数バイトにまたがる数値が存在するようなら)指定し バイト列へ
(バイト列を作成できたら送信など)
>>> b1 = MessageType.PUBACK.value <<4 | flagsDUP | flagsQoS2
>>> b2 = 100
>>>
>>> bs = struct.pack('!2B', b1, b2)
>>> bs.hex()
'4c64'
>>> struct.unpack('!BB', bs)
(76, 100)


ありがとうございます。　1つでも例があればここから拡張していけるのですごく助かります。　書くならCで書いてと教授から言われたので、これを参考にCで書いてみます。


MQTTプロトコルの構造をした、パケットを作成したいです。

MQTT のプロトコル レベルの実装であれば、以下に仕様がありますので、これに準拠して実装する必要があります。

https://mqtt.org/mqtt-specification/

